# Querying μ character from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
RawMaterialID   Level01 Level02 Level03          Level04    Level05        Level06  Description60Digit                                        Description30Digit
    393             POLYBAGS PB.HGR 33x46cm 30.5μm  HANGER HOLE HANGER.HOLE1.5" LDPE    PB.HGR 33x46cm 30.5μm HANGER HOLE HANGER.HOLE1.5" LDPE  PB.HGR 33x46cm 30.5μm
```

I am trying to retrieve the row above using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[RawMaterial] 
WHERE [Level01] = 'POLYBAGS' 
  AND [Level02] = 'PB.HGR' 
  AND [Level03] = '33x46cm 30.5μm' 
  AND [Level04] = 'HANGER HOLE' 
  AND [Level05] = 'HANGER.HOLE1.5"' 
  AND [Level06] = 'LDPE'
```

The query fails because of the 'μ' character in the `Level03` column, is there any workaround for the this ?

Table design:

```
[RawMaterialID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RMProcurementGroupID] [int] NULL,
[Level01] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Level02] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Level03] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Level04] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Level05] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Level06] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Description60Digit] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Description30Digit] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[RawMaterialTypeID] [int] NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make a test using:

```
AND [Level03]=N'33x46cm 30.5μm'
```

tell the system that the string to compare is `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if it solved your problem.